# Javascript issue IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have code snippet 
    document.attachEvent("onclick", func);

whenever there is a click event I am getting this error 
JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'attachEvent'

I am using Jquery 1.2.6 version .

Comment: jQuery isn't the problem ... obviously IE11 uses the standard `element.addEventListener('click' ...)` as opposed to the microsoft attachEvent

Comment: jQuery v1.2.6 became outdated when jQuery v1.3.0 was released on **January 14th, 2009**. I would strongly recommend that you not continue to use a library that's more than six years out of date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`attachEvent` was a Microsoft innovation which has been replaced by the DOM2 standard `addEventListener`, even in Microsoft's most recent browsers.

So change

```
document.attachEvent("onclick", func);
```

to

```
document.addEventListener("click", func, false);
```

Of course, that will fail on older IE.

Or, as you say you're using jQuery, you can sidestep the whole issue:

```
$(document).bind("click", func);   // Antiquated jQuery
```

I would also **strongly recommend** you use an up-to-date version of jQuery, as v1.2.6 is **ancient** in web terms. If you use something recent, then you'd use:

```
$(document).on("click", func);     // Current jQuery
```

Comment: document.addEventListener("click", func, false); what false stands for

Comment: @PoonamSinghania: `false` means that you want the event's bubbling phase rather than its capturing phase. `attachEvent` and jQuery *only* support the bubbling phase. On modern browsers you can leave the third argument off, but some older ones may still require it. [See this part of the DOM3 events spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow).